# How can I create two DS series virtual machines within the same cloud service?

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-virtual-machine, azure-cloud-services

I need to create two DS virtual machines within the same cloud service. In the existing portal this is very easy, however in the preview portal there appears to be no options to set the cloud service when creating a VM.

The problem is that the existing portal cannot create DS virtual machines, or virtual machines with premium storage. Whilst the preview portal *can* create DS virtual machines, but cannot create virtual machines within a cloud service.

I have tried to create virtual machines in the existing portal as a D series VM, and then upgrade with the preview portal to a DS VM but this option is not available.

I am hoping I am missing something obvious.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A central feature of a cloud service is a shared DNS name which provides a VIP and a load balancer. In the preview portal this capability is exposed through a shared DNS name. Give your second VM the same DNS name as your first VM.